# R - Round number to nearest unevenly spaced custom value

Tags: r, rounding

I am trying to round consectutive years to the nearest year that a census took place. Unfortunately, in NZ the spacing between census is not always consistent. Eg. I want to round years 2000 to 2020 to the nearest value of 2001, 2006, 2013, 2018. Is there a way to do this without resorting to a series of `if_else` or `case_when` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to find the minimum absolute difference between the two vectors.

Suppose your vectors were like this:

```r
census_years <- c(2001, 2006, 2013, 2018)
all_years <- 2000:2020
```

Then you can do:

```r
sapply(all_years, function(x) census_years[which.min(abs(census_years - x))])
#>  [1] 2001 2001 2001 2001 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013
#> [16] 2013 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `findInterval`

```
census_year[findInterval(year_in_question, census_year)+1]
#[1] 2013
```

#### data

```
census_year <- c(2001, 2006, 2013, 2018)
year_in_question <- 2012
```

Comment: Hmm. This one seems to act more like `floor` than `round`. Also, it requires that the year in question always falls within the bounds of the census years (eg. 2019 returns `NA`).

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, by finding the smallest difference between the year and the census years. Vectorizing is left as an exercise...

```
require(magrittr)

census_year <- c(2001, 2006, 2013, 2018)
year_in_question <- 2012

abs(census_year - year_in_question) %>%  # abs diff in years
  which.min() %>%  # index number of the smallest abs difference
  census_year[.]   # use that index number

[1] 2013
```